# antlr infinit eof loop

Tags: antlr, infinite-loop, eof

Please have a look at my grammar: https://bitbucket.org/rstoll/tsphp-parser/raw/cdb41531e86ec66416403eb9c29edaf60053e5df/src/main/antlr/TSPHP.g

Somehow ANTLR produces an infinite loop finding infinite EOF tokens for the following input:

```
class a{public function void a(}
```

Although, only prog expects EOF classBody somehow accept it as well. Has someone an idea how I can fix that, what I have to change that classBody does not accept EOF tokens respectively?

Code from the generated class:

```
// D:\\TSPHP-parser\\src\\main\\antlr\\TSPHP.g:287:129: ( classBody )*
loop17:
do {
    int alt17=2;
    int LA17_0 = input.LA(1);
    if ( (LA17_0==EOF||LA17_0==Abstract||LA17_0==Const||LA17_0==Final||LA17_0==Function||LA17_0==Private||(LA17_0 >= Protected && LA17_0 <= Public)||LA17_0==Static) ) {
        alt17=1;
    }

    switch (alt17) {
    case 1 :
        // D:\\TSPHP-parser\\src\\main\\antlr\\TSPHP.g:287:129: classBody
        {
        pushFollow(FOLLOW_classBody_in_classDeclaration1603);
        classBody38=classBody();
        state._fsp--;
        if (state.failed) return retval;
        if ( state.backtracking==0 ) stream_classBody.add(classBody38.getTree());
        }
        break;

    default :
        break loop17;
    }
} while (true);
```

The problem occurs, when token = EOF, the loop is never quit, since EOF is a valid token, even though I haven not specified like that.

**EDIT** The do not get the error if I comment line 342 and 347 out (the empty case in rule accessModifierWithoutPrivateOrPublic, accessModifierOrPublic respectively)

***EDIT 2*** I could solve my problem. I rewrote the methodModifier rule (integrated all the possible modifier in one rule). This way ANTLR does not believe that EOF is a valid token after /*empty*/ in

```
accessModifierOrPublic
    :   accessModifier 
    |   /* empty */ -> Public["public"]
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of bug can occur in error handling for ANTLR 3. In ANTLR 4, the [`IntStream.consume()`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#consume%28%29)  method was updated to require the following exception be thrown to preempt this problem.

> Throws:
>   `IllegalStateException` - if an attempt is made to consume the the end of the stream (i.e. if [`LA(1)`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#LA%28int%29)`==`[`EOF`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#LA%28int%29) before calling consume).

For ANTLR 3 grammars, you can at least prevent an infinite loop by using your own [`TokenStream`](http://antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/TokenStream.html) implementation (probably easiest to extend [`CommonTokenStream`](http://antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/CommonTokenStream.html)) and throwing this exception if the condition listed above is violated. Note that you *might* need to allow this condition to be violated once (reasons are complicated), so keep a count and throw the `IllegalStateException` if the code tries to consume EOF more than 2 or 3 times. Remember this is just an effort to break the infinite loop so you can be a little "fuzzy" on the actual check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could solve the problem using predicates. cheered too soon, I forgot to add ? to the accessModifier and got the same problem again afterwards. I will try your approach

Comment: I could solve the problem by rewriting some rules. New grammar can be found here (for those who have the same problem):https://bitbucket.org/rstoll/tsphp-parser/raw/97b4ee4b8307cc66d82725fc1b17343a46988796/src/main/antlr/TSPHP.g